# Changing the key name in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

How can I change the key name in an array of objects?

```
var arrayObj = [{key1:'value1', key2:'value2'},{key1:'value1', key2:'value2'}];
```

How can I change each `key1` to `stroke` so that I get:

```
var arrayObj = [{stroke:'value1', key2:'value2'},{stroke:'value1', key2:'value2'}];
```

Comment: Here several years later, rather than the [currently-accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6809691/157247), you'd use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50951372/157247) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53317252/157247) using an arrow function.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
var i;
for(i = 0; i < arrayObj.length; i++){
    arrayObj[i].stroke = arrayObj[i]['key1'];
    delete arrayObj[i].key1;
}
```

Comment: You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/XVxvy/2/ It alerts "undefined" and then "value1"

Comment: Thanks for the solution but what If the object is with dynamic key? like: var arrayObj = [{abcKey,'value1', acdKey:'value2',defKey:'value3', cfgKey:'value4'}];

Comment: it remove the key, what should i do :(

Answer (score 92):

In recent JavaScript (and TypeScript), use [destructuring with rest syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and [array `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to replace one of the key strings in an array of objects.

```js
const arrayOfObj = [{
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2'
}, {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2'
}];
const newArrayOfObj = arrayOfObj.map(({
  key1: stroke,
  ...rest
}) => ({
  stroke,
  ...rest
}));

console.log(newArrayOfObj);
```

Comment: Spread is optional, It's just there if you want to keep your old values in your array.
Nice answer, really neat and powerful nonetheless.

Comment: How to make "stroke" dynamically passed to map function?

Comment: @Prashant, good question (how to pass 'stroke' dynamically)! Would the following code work for you? ```const newKey = 'stroke'; const newArrayOfObj = arrayOfObj.map(({ key1, ...rest }) => ({ [newKey]: key1, ...rest }));```

Comment: Note, this doesn't replace anything.  It makes a new array with new property names.

Comment: Is it possible to use this on nested attributes, e.g. const arrayOfObj = [{attributes: {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2'
}}, {attributes: {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2'
}}];?

Answer (score 37):

ES6 [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```js
let arrayObj = [{key1:'value1', key2:'value2'},{key1:'value1', key2:'value2'}];

arrayObj = arrayObj.map(item => {
  return {
    stroke: item.key1,
    key2: item.key2
  };
});
    
console.log("arrayObj = " + JSON.stringify(arrayObj));
```

Comment: But you need to know all the keys in the object and also write each of them in the returning object.

Comment: you dont need to know all the keys, you can just use the spread operator like this:   var arrayObj = [{key1:'value1', key2:'value2'},{key1:'value1', key2:'value2'}];

arrayObj = arrayObj.map(item => {
      return {
        ...item,
        key2: item.key2
      };
    });

Comment: but this also keeps the old keys

Comment: Don't think so, try running the code snippet.

Answer (score 20):

You can't change a property name, you have to add the value with a new name and delete the old property:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayObj.length; i++) {
  arrayObj[i].stroke = arrayObj[i].key1;
  delete arrayObj[i].key1;
}
```

Comment: Is `delete` supported by all browser versions?

Comment: Yes, it's part of the Javascript language.

Comment: Ok, for some reason I thought it was not supported by some versions of IE or something.

Answer (score 17):

just one line of code needed with ES6

try following code :

```
arrayObj.map(({ stroke, key2 }) => ({ yourNewKey: stroke, yourNewKey2: key2 }));
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
const company =  [{ id:"1", name:"somename"},{ id:"1", name:"somename"}]

company.map(({ id, name }) => ({ companyId: id, companyName: name }));

// output
//[{ companyId:"1", companyName:"somename"},{ companyId:"1", //companyName:"somename"}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't change a key name.  You can assign a new key name/value and then remove the previous key if you want.  In your example:

```
var arrayObj = [{key1,'value1', key2:'value2'},{key1,'value1', key2:'value2'}];
var o = arrayObj[0];   // get first object
var val = o.key1;      // get current value
o.stroke = val;        // assign to new key
delete o.key1;         // remove previous key
```

If you wanted to do that for all the objects in your main array, you would just put that in a loop that iterates over the contents of your array.  I've put more intermediate assignments in here than neccessary just to document what's going on.

Or a shortened version in a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayObj.length; i++) {
    var o = arrayObj[i];
    o.stroke = o.key1;
    delete o.key1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. As much as I like ES5/6 I had to do this in google tag manager and use vanilla js.

Comment: @lharby - this is vanilla js already.  This would work in es3.

Comment: that's what I meant some of the newer es5/6 features are NOT supported in gtm. So thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
function changeKey(originalKey, newKey, arr)
{
  var newArr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    var obj = arr[i];
    obj[newKey] = obj[originalKey];
    delete(obj[originalKey]);
    newArr.push(obj);
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

pure javascript

```js
var array=[{oldkey:'oldkeyvalue',oldkey2:'oldkey2'}]
var result=array.map(({ oldkey: newkey, ...rest }) => ({ newkey, ...rest }));
console.log(result)
```

lodash or underscore js

```
//Lodash/underscore.js
_.map(array,(({ oldkey: newkey, ...rest }))=>({ oldkey: newkey, ...rest }))
```

The above technique cant set  string name

eg:full name or last name

wrong way:

```
name:full name
```

right way

```
name:full_name
```

you can achieve string object in same way using map

```
array.map((x)=>{
var y={};
//also use spread operator if necessary but key want to remove manually

y['full name']=x['name'];
return y;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, when you have other arrays, and they have objects with different keys names and your objects they have equal size.

```
function convertKeys (arr) {
  const newFormat = arr.map((value) => {
    const arrFormat = Object.values(value)
    return {
      newKey1: arrFormat[0],
      newKey2: arrFormat[1]
    }
  })
}
```

In array.map, i converted the object to an array and got the values ​​by their index.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please explain your answer a little in textual form and tell us, how it works and what makes it different from the other answers given.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an immutable way of changing an object.
You can also add new key-value pairs to the object

```js
let arrayOfObj = [{id:"0",name:'myName'},{id:"2",name:'myNewName'}]
const newArr = arrayOfObj.map(item => ({ ...item, id : Number(item.id),someRandomKey:'RandomValue' }))
console.log(newArr)
```