# How to change the keys in one object with javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, frontend

I have:

```
    var myAbc = { 0: true, 1: false, 2: true };
```

and i want to change de keys like:

```
var myAbc = { key1: true, key2: false, key3: true };
```

i have already tried this:

```
 for (var key in array) {
            key = value;
        }
```

but did not change the key of the array out side of the for, any help?

Comment: myAbc is not an array its an object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the key name in an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809659/changing-the-key-name-in-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use es6, you can do this in one line:

```js
var myAbc = { 0: true, 1: false, 2: true };

var renamed = Object.keys(myAbc).reduce((p, c) => { p[`key${Number(c)+1}`] = myAbc[c]; return p; }, {})

console.log(renamed)
```

Comment: As noted by @Derek朕會功夫, this creates a new object with your desired keys (which is not the same as renaming existing keys). It can be reassigned back onto `myAbc`, but any existing references to `myAbc` will not be updated. If you want to mutate the object, Derek's answer will do that. That said, imo, you should avoid mutation anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this perhaps?

```
for(let key in myAbc){
    myAbc["key" + key] = myAbc[key];
    delete myAbc[key];
}
```

```js
var myAbc = { 0: true, 1: false, 2: true };
console.log("Before", myAbc);

for(let key in myAbc){
    myAbc["key" + key] = myAbc[key];
    delete myAbc[key];
}
console.log("After", myAbc);
```

Comment: You're right -- this is better if you actually want to change the object rather than create a new one.

Comment: This is shorter and easier to follow, +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
function changeObjectKeys(sourceObject, prepondText){
    var updatedObj = {};
    for(var key in sourceObject){
        updatedObj[prepondText + key] = sourceObject[key];
    }
    return updatedObj;
}
```

Check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/WasimBeniwale/g00vfjqk/)