# How to change the key betwen objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, typescript, object

i have:

```
var first = { 0: true, 1: false, 2: true };

    var second = [
      { name: 'car', value: false },
      { name: 'bike', value: false },
      { name: 'moto', value: false }];
```

and i want to change the key of the first based on second like:

```
first = { car: true, bike: false, moto: true };
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? This seems to be relatively simple problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214090/how-to-change-the-keys-in-one-object-with-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the keys in one object with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214090/how-to-change-the-keys-in-one-object-with-javascript)

Comment: I don't think you've put enough effort in trying to solve the question. It's too simple.

Comment: @CarlesAndres It's not that simple, it requires knowledge of a `for..in` loop minimum, how would you solve this problem ?

Comment: @Taurus You need to learn some basic Javascript before you can do it, of course, like [forEach](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/foreach). You know the saying "give a man a fish and he'll eat for one day, teach him how to fish and he'll eat forever".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate the array and update the object `first`. Then delete the used property.

```js
var first = { 0: true, 1: false, 2: true },
    second = [{ name: 'car', value: false }, { name: 'bike', value: false }, { name: 'moto', value: false }];
    
second.forEach(function (o, i) {
    first[o.name] = first[i];
    delete first[i];
});

console.log(first);
```

Comment: Thanks, i guess my problem was to acess the keys properties correctly, i see in your code you accessing in the right way. New guy in javascript, sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you tried something...

If I understood the issue, you can code:

```
var firstTemp = first;
for(var f in firstTemp){
    first[second[f].name]=first[f];
    first[f]=null;
}
firstTemp = null;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this `firstTemp` variable ? Isn't it just useless ?