# JSON : Convert Json For Chart CanvasJS

Tags: javascript, json, encode

I'm working with chart using [Canvas JS](https://canvasjs.com/) , I have problem  to fetch data .
I have result `json_encode()` like this :

```
[{“jumlah_berita”:2,”nama_kategori”:”Music”},{“jumlah_berita”:1,”nama_kategori”:”Sport”},{“jumlah_berita”:1,”nama_kategori”:”Agama”},{“jumlah_berita”:0,”nama_kategori”:”Teknologi”},{“jumlah_berita”:1,”nama_kategori”:”Pendidikan”},{“jumlah_berita”:0,”nama_kategori”:”Cinta”},{“jumlah_berita”:0,”nama_kategori”:”coba test”}]
```

I already read documentation [Canvas JS](https://canvasjs.com/) about [Accepted Data CanvasJS](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/working-with-data/), It's mean my json not valid.

My Question is, How to convert `JSON`

#### From:

```
[
 {“jumlah_berita”:2,”nama_kategori”:”Music”}, 
 {“jumlah_berita”:1,”nama_kategori”:”Sport”}, 
 {“jumlah_berita”:1,”nama_kategori”:”Agama”}, 
 {“jumlah_berita”:0,”nama_kategori”:”Teknologi”}, 
 {“jumlah_berita”:1,”nama_kategori”:”Pendidikan”}, 
 {“jumlah_berita”:0,”nama_kategori”:”Cinta”}, 
 {“jumlah_berita”:0,”nama_kategori”:”coba test”}
]
```

#### To :

```
[{y:2,label:"Music"},
{y:1,label:"Sport"},
{y:1,label:"Agama"},
{y:0,label:"Teknologi"},
{y:2,label:"Pendidikan"}]
```

Thank's

> It's My code to make Chart

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var tampil_kategori = '<?= $tampil_kategori ?>';
        var newdataPoints = JSON.parse(tampil_kategori);
        var jumlahBerita = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2", {
            animationEnabled: true,
            theme: "light2", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
            title: {
                text: "Jumlah Berita(per Kategori)"
            },

            data: [{
                type: "column",
                dataPoints: newdataPoints
            }]
        });

        jumlahBerita.render();

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the key name in an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809659/changing-the-key-name-in-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const to = from.map(item => ({
  y: item.jumlah_berita,
  label: item.nama_kategori
}));
```

**EDIT**

```
window.onload = function() {
    var tampil_kategori = [
       {“jumlah_berita”:2,”nama_kategori”:”Music”}, 
       {“jumlah_berita”:1,”nama_kategori”:”Sport”}, 
       {“jumlah_berita”:1,”nama_kategori”:”Agama”}, 
       {“jumlah_berita”:0,”nama_kategori”:”Teknologi”}, 
       {“jumlah_berita”:1,”nama_kategori”:”Pendidikan”}, 
       {“jumlah_berita”:0,”nama_kategori”:”Cinta”}, 
       {“jumlah_berita”:0,”nama_kategori”:”coba test”}
    ];

    // map here --------------------------------
    var newdataPoints = tampil_kategori.map(item => ({
        y: item.jumlah_berita,
       label: item.nama_kategori
    }));
    // -----------------------------------------

    var jumlahBerita = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2", {
        animationEnabled: true,
        theme: "light2", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
        title: {
            text: "Jumlah Berita(per Kategori)"
        },

        data: [{
            type: "column",
            dataPoints: newdataPoints
        }]
    });

    jumlahBerita.render();

}
```

Comment: `var tampil_kategori = '<?= $tampil_kategori ?>';` `const to = tampil_kategori.map(item => ({
   y: item.jumlah_berita,
   label: item.nama_kategori
  }));`  . I'm already follow but i get error , `Uncaught TypeError: tampil_kategori.map is not a function`

Comment: updated answer, maybe that's more clear.  If `newdataPoints` is in that format you mentioned in your question then this should work