# how to iterate over two responses one after another using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am initialized one variable with two responses from two async calls like this below.

```
const items = await service.fetchDropdownFieldItems(payload.url);
```

It is storing the responses one after another and it is working fine. Those responses are like below:

```
1st response :  [{id:1, value:'Shoe'},{id:2,value:'Boutique'},{id:3,value:'Clothing'}]

2nd response:   {data:[{country_id:1, country_name:'Australia'},{country_id:2,country_name:'France'},{country_id:3,country_name:'USA'}]}
```

Now, i want to format 2nd response's data array and replace the 2nd response with my formatted response.

Now, if i check **items** variable it should contain like this

```
1st response :  [{id:1, value:'Shoe'},{id:2,value:'Boutique'},{id:3,value:'Clothing'}]

2nd response:   [{id:1, value:'Australia'},{id:2, value:'France'},{id:3, value:'USA'}]}
```

Any approach for doing like this. There is no issue on async call or url etc. Only i want to change the response and replace with old one.

Comment: Do you just want to change the keys names in your second array? [Changing the key name in an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6809659) If so, I don't see what the relevance is of the first array to the question? Is the first array supposed to be used in a particular way?

Comment: I am storing two responses into one variable one after another. How to map two responses with id ? Then 2nd response will replace with formatted response.

Answer (score 1):

```
const formattedResponse = response.data.map((entry)=>({
    id: entry.country_id,
    value: entry.country_name
} ) )
```

you might place this logic somewhere inside **service.fetchDropdownFieldItems**, so you don't need to manually change your data everytime you fetch the items

### Edit

Here is an example of how to use it inside a fetching function. You can change **fetch** with **axios** if you prefer

```
const formatResponse=(data)=>{
    return data.map((entry)=>({
        id: entry.country_id,
        value: entry.country_name
    } ) )
}
```

```
const fetchDropdownFieldItems =(url, options={})=>{
    return fetch(url, options)
        .then(res=> res.json())
        .then(res=>res.data)
        .then(formatResponse) //shorthand for .then(data=> formatResponse(data)
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
fetchDropdownFieldItems(...).then(doSomething)

//same as
fetchDropdownFieldItems(...).then(formattedData => doSomething(formattedData))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How to place the logic somewhere there? Can you just give any example?

Comment: Yes i want this approach.

Comment: I added an example to the answer 

Comment: Not sure how **service.fetchDropdownFieldItems(payload.url)** was implemented, might be helpful to see the code in order to provide the best solution

Comment: See this question.... Here is the order.... You are correct that logic i want to implement somewhere in between service and action.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67089921/reusable-dropdown-fields-in-form-component-using-vuex-and-vue

Comment: The cleanest approch is probably to have 2 different fetching  functions: `const items = await url === '...' ? service.fetchItemsOfDrowdown1(url) : service.fetchItemsOfDrowdown2(url) ` (syntax has to be improved but I hope you get the idea)

Answer (score 0):

```
const processData = (response) => {
 const dataArray = [];
  response.data.forEach(({country_id,country_name})=>{
   dataArray.push({ id: country_id, value: country_name });
  })
 return dataArray;
}
```

This answer is the same as previous one but, takes less **time to execute**, and a little bit **optimized**

or also be used as

```
const processData = (response) => {
  return response.data.map(({country_id,country_name})=>({ id: country_id, value: country_name }))
}
```

Comment: if you're returning an array from looping an array, use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) or  [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), it make things so much simpler 

Answer (score 0):

**[].map** should do the trick

```js
const res2 = {
  data: [{
    country_id: 1,
    country_name: 'Australia'
  }, {
    country_id: 2,
    country_name: 'France'
  }, {
    country_id: 3,
    country_name: 'USA'
  }]
}

const result2 = res2.data.map(v => ({
  id: v.country_id,
  value: v.country_name
}))
console.log(result2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How to map over two responses with id 0 and 1 . Because i am storing two responses into one items variable.? Anything i can do for this??