# change json attribute na,e before save using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

this is the sample json format in my application.

```
my arr =    [
    {
        "id": 12,
        "creationTimestamp": "2021-09-15 15:01:11",
        "groupName": "one",
        "$$hashKey": "object:15"
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "creationTimestamp": "2021-09-15 15:01:14",
        "groupName": "two",
        "$$hashKey": "object:16"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "creationTimestamp": "2021-09-15 15:01:19",
        "groupName": "three",
        "$$hashKey": "object:17"
    }
]
```

according to my requirement i need to change id --> groupId. After i need to assign it for the new array

```
 my array2       [
        {
            "groupId": 12,
            "creationTimestamp": "2021-09-15 15:01:11",
            "groupName": "one",
            "$$hashKey": "object:15"
        },
        {
            "groupId": 13,
            "creationTimestamp": "2021-09-15 15:01:14",
            "groupName": "two",
            "$$hashKey": "object:16"
        },
        {
            "groupId": 14,
            "creationTimestamp": "2021-09-15 15:01:19",
            "groupName": "three",
            "$$hashKey": "object:17"
        }
    ]
```

how i do this modification using java script

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809659/changing-the-key-name-in-an-array-of-objects/50951372

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the key name in an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809659/changing-the-key-name-in-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const my_arr = [
  {
    id: 12,
    creationTimestamp: "2021-09-15 15:01:11",
    groupName: "one",
    $$hashKey: "object:15",
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    creationTimestamp: "2021-09-15 15:01:14",
    groupName: "two",
    $$hashKey: "object:16",
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    creationTimestamp: "2021-09-15 15:01:19",
    groupName: "three",
    $$hashKey: "object:17",
  },
];

const result = my_arr.map(({ id, ...rest }) => ({ groupId: id, ...rest }));
console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use the `Object` and `Array`  methods  in js .. See Below

```
  let myArray =    [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "creationTimestamp": "2021-09-15 15:01:11",
            "groupName": "one",
            "$$hashKey": "object:15"
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "creationTimestamp": "2021-09-15 15:01:14",
            "groupName": "two",
            "$$hashKey": "object:16"
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "creationTimestamp": "2021-09-15 15:01:19",
            "groupName": "three",
            "$$hashKey": "object:17"
        }
    ]

    let newArray = [];

    myArray.forEach(obj =>{
        Object.assign(obj , { groupId : obj.id}  );
        delete obj.id;
        newArray.push(obj);
    });

    console.log(newArray);
```

> References : [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)